# Selecting objects by version number

Tags: mysql

I have an app version such as 2.15.3.

I have module versions for the apps that begin with the first two characters of the app version. So a module version might be 2.15.1.8.

The module versions numbers are stored as a varchar column called version.

Modules only work with the app version if the following two conditions are true:

- The first number of the module = the first number of the app
- The second number of the module <= the second number of the app

I want to be able to select all modules out of a table that match the above two rules.

So for app 2.15.3, it should return 2.15.1.8, but not 2.16.1.2, and not 1.14.1.2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found a way (though am open to critique):

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE substring_index(version, '.', 1) = :APP_NUM_ONE
AND substring_index(substring_index(version, '.', 2), '.', -1) <= :APP_NUM_TWO;
```

Where, in this scenario :APP_NUM_ONE = 2, and :APP_NUM_TWO = 15.